# C#. Webbrowser. Некорректно работает Javascript.Как исправить?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Добрый день. В программу внедрен компонент WebBrowser. Через него по адресу https://avotron.ru/catalog/to/bmw/ не работает пагинация. Точнее первый ряд открывается, а второй и последующий не работают.. Есть идеи товарищи знатоки? Заранее благодарен

ScriptErrorsSuppressed включен для WebBrowser.

Comment: так там убогий браузер

Comment: WebBrowser использует движок ишака (IE), причем, по-моему, не самой свежей версии. Тут сделать практически ничего нельзя. Этот контрол годится для работы со статичными самыми простыми html страничками.